# Stop jQuery keyup from triggering with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I'm trying to create an email validation field that shows an error message if the email doesn't fit the standards. For this I used keyup as event so the message would be visible as soon as the user entered a wrong email.

But this way every time the user enters a character the message shows, so I thought I would add a delay and found a function for this but this does indeed add a delay but still shows every time the message gets triggered.

Does someone know how to make sure the event only gets called once after the user has stopped for a certain time period?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cypkcygf/)**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="email" value="supplier@supplier.com">
        </td>
        <td><span class="message"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
function isEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}

$('.email').on('keyup', function() {
    var delay = (function() {
        var timer = 0;
        return function(callback, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();

    var email = $('.email').val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.message').hide();

    if (isEmail(email) == false) {
        delay(function() {
            $('.email').closest('tr').find('.message').hide().html('Invalid email.').fadeIn('fast');
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.message').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why you need the delay buddy?looks like it will work without delay as well

Comment: Remove delay and use 'blur' event instead of 'keyup'

Comment: @santhucool Because I'm fading the message in so it is easy to notice for the user that there input gets validated everytime they enter something, but without the delay the message just keeps fading in everytime the user types something which is a bit overkill if you ask me. So I thought I would only trigger the keyup event of the user was done typing

Comment: @amrit sandhu I would like to have the validation triggered while the email input is still active

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your timeout is a little flawed in the above. Note that a better method which allows users to enter their email without validation the first time is to check the validity of the email on blur of the input. If you wanted to you could then check validity of the email after every keypress following the first blur event. Something like this:

```
function checkEmailValidity($el) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    var $msg = $el.closest('tr').find('.message').hide();
    if (!regex.test($el.val()))
        $msg.html('Invalid email.').fadeIn('fast');
}

var timer;    
$('.email').on({ 
    blur: function() {
        $(this).data('hasBlurred', true);
        checkEmailValidity($(this));
    },
    keyup: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).data('hasBlurred') && checkEmailValidity($(this)); 
        }.bind(this), 250);
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1rtL2a9e/)

Comment: It's because the email is for an order which is already set at another time. But can still be altert before sending out the order. So it's possible the user would only need to change .com to .net instead of re-entering the whole email. So the ideal situation would be to delay the keyup event until after the user was done typing for a certain amount of time.